# how to know the path,where the errors and warnings are stored in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, programming-languages, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

My doubt is related to the storage of `Error/Warning Messages`.

For example I wrote a `C` program in `Eclipse IDE` and compiled. The Error/Warning Messages are displayed in the problem tab.

If this is the situation which file in my computer contains the Error/Warning Messages. I need to know the location of this file because I am doing a project related to `IDE` creation.

Any suggestions or Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should know that what you see in Problems view in eclipse has not been saved as a log file in plain text. But if you want to see it: 
1- Under each workspace there is a folder named ".metadata" . In linux it is a hide folder and you have to choose show hide files. I am not sure about windows.

2- open this path  ".plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/" under ".metadata".

3- choose the sub folder with the project name. (The project you want to see prolems for it).

4- there is two files holding the problems named ".markers" and ".markers.snap"

As said this is under Linux. Under windows may be it differs. But it should be something like this.

Not every text editor opens these files. I used emacs!